# Is there a way to check if DisplayObject A is a descendant of DisplayObject B?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, displayobject

I would like to be able to quickly check if a given DisplayObject is a descendant (not in the inheritance sense - ie. child, grandchild, great-grandchild, great-great-grandchild, etc.) of another DisplayObject.

There doesn't seem to be a native way to do this and I can only think of two ways to achieve it:

1. Create the mother of all nested loops. Seems a bit, I dunno, wrong?
2. Dispatch a bubbling event at the 'child' and check if the potential 'parent' receives it.

Am trying the latter now, but would appreciate some input. I'd like to create a nice utility static function, eg:

```
static public function isDescendantOf(child:DisplayObject, parent:DisplayObjectContainer):Boolean { 

    var isDescendant: Boolean = false;

    // perform some magical 
    // check that returns true 
    // if it is a descendant

    return isDescendant;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Holy horned moose, event for that...

```
parent.contains(child);
```

See reference for [DisplayObjectContainer.contains()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#contains%28%29).

Comment: Oh man, I was so excited about my weird solution too. Thanks a bunch! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working, but it uses a nasty anonymous function.

Wonder if it can be improved?

```
static public function isDescendantOf(child:DisplayObject, parent:DisplayObjectContainer):Boolean {
    const HELLO:String = "hello";
    var isDescendant:Boolean = false;

    parent.addEventListener(HELLO, function(e:Event):void {
       isDescendant = true;
    });

    child.dispatchEvent(new Event(HELLO, true, false));
    return isDescendant;
}
```