# How to removechild IF it's visible

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game in AS3 when you can save and restore your game.

The player can load his saved game at the introscreen OR during the game.

I've got an error (not very important as the game is still working but I'd like to correct in order to be clean) as I don't know how to put it in code.

So, when the player click on "load" at the Introscreen, a window opens where he can choose wich games he wants to restore.

When he choose a game, he click on it and the IntroScreen AND the restore window disappear. 
Here's the code for this :

```
if(allSaveData){
..
dispatchEvent(new Event("closeThis"));
this.parent.removeChild(introScreen);
}
```

But when he's in the game and he wants to restore. He clicks on "esc" and the restore windows appears. But the IntroScreen IS NOT HERE. So when he restore his game, I've got an error with "this.parent.removeChild(introScreen);" as IntroScreen is not here.

I've tried this :

```
if(allSaveData){
    ..
    dispatchEvent(new Event("closeThis"));
                } 
                if (introScreen.visible == true){
                this.parent.removeChild(introScreen);
    }
```

But it's not working. 
Do you know how I can tell the code "if introscreen is here close it, if not don't" ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Seems like `contains()` method is  relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022966/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-displayobject-a-is-a-descendant-of-displayobject-b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`visible` is to show/hide a display object. You can't use this to determine whether the object is added in display list or not. There are a number of options to achieve this.

Option 1: Check the `parent` property of `introScreen`.

```
if (introScreen.parent) {
    introScreen.parent.removeChild(introScreen);
}
```

Option 2: Use the `contains` method.

```
if (this.parent.contains(introScreen)) {
    this.parent.removeChild(introScreen);
}
```

Option 3: Use try-catch block and simply ignore the error.

```
try {
    this.parent.removeChild(introScreen);
} catch(err:Error) {
    // ignore the error when it's not present
}
```

Comment: may be it is better to check if the child is in the display list is to check if it has the `stage` defined? like `if(introScreen.stage)` ?

Comment: @Cherniv, but `stage` will be valid if it's added in some other parent, i.e. `this.parent.removeChild(introScreen)` will still throw error if `introScreen` is added in some container other than `this.parent`. But I agree, for this particular case this might not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try
introScreen.parent.removeChild(introScreen)